# Entitlement and Support Record Update Rule Detail doesn't works for Closed Cases?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I am using OOTB Entitlement Process and Milestone in our application. On Prod, I already have 1 active version of Entitlement Process having 4 milestones running under it. Few Milestone start time uses picklist value "Entitlement Process". This picklist value I need to changed to Milestone criteria. Once I do that its working fine as per business requirement for all the new cases.

On Prod, almost have 100 cases out of which 47 are closed cases. I performed the **Entitlement and Support Record Update Rule Detail** from old version of Entitlement process to newer version all the dates updated correctly for Open cases, but of the date updated for the closed cases.

Could anyone please suggest how to fixed it ? Please let me know if need any other details from my side.

Comment: What does the status show, does it show "Completed" or "Completed With Exceptions"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I have run update rules multiple times on an entitlement process which covers a large number of records. Every time I run an update, the rule fails to update all cases and entitlements. The failure is on a very small percentage of records, leaving me with several dozen or maybe a few hundred cases stuck on the old version of the entitlement process. The larger issue that causes is the inability of delete obsolete versions of the entitlement process.